# How to get an item index in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, indexing

I have two list.

The first list contains languages and contains about `30000` items.

```
['es','de', 'ita', ....]
```

The second list contains about twenty language codes, as follow :

```
['eng', 'ar', 'fr', 'ch', 'jp', 'ita' .... ]
```

What I want to do is to search and see if the `1`st book is related to the code `19` ( 1 is the index of the book in the first list) and if found, print the code index from the second list

```
import csv

book_language_list = []
with open('language_table_for_search.csv', 'r') as rf:
    reader = csv.reader(rf, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
      book_language_list.append(row[2])


book_language_distinc = []
with open('language_codes.csv', 'r') as rf:
    reader = csv.reader(rf, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
      book_language_distinc.append(row[1])


for i in range(0, len(book_language_list)):    
    if any(book_language_list[i] in s for s in book_language_distinc):
        # print the book id=i has language=(found language index)
```

Comment: What is the problem which you are facing?

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes thats the problem

Comment: Easier to iterate `for lang in book_language_list` and then get the index against the other list, as the ansewr below suggests. No need to do an indexed loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved as follow, using `enumerate` :

```
for i in range(0, len(book_language_list)):    
    print("book {} has language {}={}".format(i, book_language_list[i], [j for j, s in enumerate(book_language_distinc) if book_language_list[i] in s]))
```

output :

```
book 27279 has language 'us'=[5]
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use the index function, from the documentation:

> This method returns index of the found object otherwise raise an
>   exception indicating that value does not find.

Like this:

```
books = ['es', 'de', 'ita', 'eng']
codes = ['eng', 'ar', 'fr', 'ch', 'jp', 'ita']

for book in books:
    try:
        ii = codes.index(book)
        print(book, ii)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Output:

```
ita 5
eng 0
```

If you have multiple languages by book and that each book is represented by a list, you can do it like this:

```
books = [['es'], ['de'], ['ita', 'ch'], ['eng']]
codes = {code: ii for ii, code in enumerate(['eng', 'ar', 'fr', 'ch', 'jp', 'ita'])}

for book in books:
    book_codes = [(lang, codes[lang]) for lang in book if lang in codes]
    if book_codes:
        print(book_codes)
```

Output:

```
[('ita', 5), ('ch', 3)]
[('eng', 0)]
```

The line:

```
codes = {code: ii for ii, code in enumerate(['eng', 'ar', 'fr', 'ch', 'jp', 'ita'])}
```

creates a dictionary where the **keys** are the language codes and the **values** the index on the list. Finally,

```
book_codes = [(lang, codes[lang]) for lang in book if lang in codes]
```

get the languages of the book that are in codes, if the list is not empty the result is printed.

Comment: The problem is some books has multiple languages and contains for example : `'eng', 'ita', 'fr'` for just one item in the list, Because of this I have to to do text search using `if any()`

Answer (score 2):

Simple Solution:
Use `set()`

`set & set` returns intersection of two sets.

example:

```
books = ['es', 'de', 'ita', 'eng']
codes = ['eng', 'ar', 'fr', 'ch', 'jp', 'ita']
for r in set(books)&set(codes):
    print(r, codes.index(r))
```

returns:

```
eng 0
ita 5
```